# How would I implement my own container with type hinting?

Tags: python, types

Say I want to make a container class `MyContainer` and I want to enable its use in type hints like `def func(container: MyContainer[SomeType])`, in a similar way to how I would be able to do `def func(ls: list[SomeType])`. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Generic` type with a `TypeVar`:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

SomeType = TypeVar('SomeType')


class MyContainer(Generic[SomeType]):

    def add(self, item: SomeType):
        ...
```

Within the definition of `MyContainer`, `SomeType` is a placeholder for whatever type a particular `MyContainer` is declared to contain.

Comment: Thanks. This answers my question. I thought someone was going to get me to implement `__class_getitem__`. I suppose that would be a bit fiddly?

Comment: I don't think that'd actually work in terms of implementing static type annotations.